# Output data from form on same page with custom BBCode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to output data from a form on the same page using javascript. I already got it to work. But I want to add something else that I can't get to work.

As you can see in the snippet below when you press submit, the data gets outputted on the same page from the input. Now I'm trying to add custom BBCode to that so my staff can post the output on the forums. (It's an interview logger).

Example: [b][/b] should be outputted on some fields, ....
I tried adding this bbcode in the javascript or the output span, but that broke the whole script.

I also had another question. If I add a dropdown or radiobutton with Pass or Fail. How would I made the output change. (Example: If Pass: [Color = Green] User has passed the interview [/color], If fail: [Color = Red] User hase failed the interview. Reason: ... [/color]

Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script language="JavaScript">
    function showInput() {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
                    document.getElementById("user_input").value;
    }
  </script>

  </head>
<body>

  <form>
    <label><b>Enter a Message</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
  </form>

  <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br/>
  <label>Your input: </label>
  <p><span id='display'></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to search by tags attributes.
Try using one `constant` to map the `id`s of the content you want add the `[B]` tag and work with `value` attribute of the `<input type="radio">` to get what you want.
Sample:

```js
const idToBold = [ 'user_input1' ];
var formInfo = {};


function showInput() {
  $('input').each(function(){
      var input = $(this);
      var value = null, label = null;
      
      //here you check every <input type="text">
      if(input.attr('type') == 'text'){
        value = input.val();
        
        //check if the id is in the constant of ids that need to add the [B] tag
        if(idToBold.includes(input.attr('id'))){
          value = '[B]' + value + '[/B]';
        }
        label = $("label[for='"+input.attr('id')+"']").text();
      }
      
      //here will check the radio with this name only, and return the checked (in case you want more radios)
      if(input.attr('name') == 'passCondition' && input.is(':checked')){      
        //check the value, theres: 'pass' and 'fail'.
        if(input.val() == 'pass'){
          value = '[Color = Green]User has passed the interview [/color]';
        }else{
          value = '[Color = Red]User hase failed the interview. Reason: ...';
        };
        label = $("label[for='"+input.attr('name')+"']").text();
      }
      
      if(label != null && label != '' && value != null && value != ''){
        formInfo[label] = value;
      }
  });
  
  //you can remove this, just for output purpose
  var formInfoFormated = '';
  jQuery.each(formInfo, function(key, value){
    formInfoFormated += key + ' : ' + value + '<br>';
  });
  $('#display').html(formInfoFormated);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
<body>

  <form>
    <label for="user_input1"><b>Enter a Message1</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input1">
    <br>
    <label for="user_input2"><b>Enter a Message2</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input2">
    
    <br><br>
    <label for="passCondition"><b>Passed?</b></label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="passCondition" value="pass">Pass<br>
    <input type="radio" name="passCondition" value="fail">Fail<br>
    <br><br>
  </form>

  <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br/>
  <label>Your input: </label>
  <p><span id='display'></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi there. would it also be possible to output this in a textarea or some other field? that would make it easier for staff to just copy everything and paste it on the forums

Comment: I was changing this one. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Thank you sir, that was exactly what I needed! Just one more thing. If I want to have more text inputs inside here. Would I change the javascript to an actual I istead input value == text? @M Jr

Comment: Would it automatically output every Text Input with a different ID or would I need to change up the JS?

Comment: Every text input that have its `id` in the const `idToBold`. :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L79a1arq/  Tried that. Doesn't seem to give me the correct output. Well it gives me nothing as output

Comment: Changed in the answer. The problem is that in the fiddle you get 'Uncaught ReferenceError: showInput is not defined'.

Comment: So if I want to add the [b] for user_input2 as well now. I just add user_input2 as an array to const idToBold?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162357/discussion-between-m-jr-and-bprepper).

Comment: Was omw back home as well, sorry for late response in chat